# cannot construct the infinite type

Tags: reductions, computer-algebra

I am trying to learn haskell and could not configure it out, why following code snippet can not get compiled:

```
*Uncurry> applyTwice f x = f f x

<interactive>:14:20: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        t ~ t -> t2 -> t1
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: f f x
      In an equation for ‘applyTwice’: applyTwice f x = f f x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: t2 (bound at <interactive>:14:14)
        f :: t -> t2 -> t1 (bound at <interactive>:14:12)
        applyTwice :: (t -> t2 -> t1) -> t2 -> t1
          (bound at <interactive>:14:1)
```

This would be fine:

```
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

In haskell function application is left associative, the first code snippet would be apply like:

```
(f f) x
```

why `(f f) x` it is wrong?

Comment: This seems like it would be a good fit to migrate to StackOverflow.

Comment: Application is left associative simply means that we write `f x y` for `((f x) y)`. It is only a notational convention. It does _not_ mean that application is associative, i.e. that `((f x) y)` must be equal to `(f (x y))`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let's look at what we know about the type of applyTwice, $\alpha$:

- It is given two arguments, so $\alpha = \beta_1 \to \beta_2 \to \gamma$, and $f$ has type $\beta\_1$ and $x$ has type $\beta_2$
- $f$ is applied to $f$, so $\beta_1 = \beta_1 \to \gamma_2$
- $(f\ f)$ is applied to $x$, so $\gamma_2 = \beta_2 \to \gamma$

The kicker here is the second equation, $\beta_1 = \beta_1 \to \gamma_2$. This equation has no finite solution, because $S \to T$ is structurally larger (uses at least one more type constructor) than either $S$ or $T$.

So the only type that satisfies this equation is infinite recursive type $\mu T\ldotp T \to \gamma_2 = ((\ldots \to \gamma\_2) \to \gamma\_2) \to \gamma\_2) \to \gamma\_2) \to \gamma\_2) \to \gamma\_2)$. But this type doesn't really have any meaning in Haskell or related type systems, and it's pretty hard represent an infinite type in finite memory in a concrete form.

Remember that $f\ f$ is giving $f$ as an argument to $f$. If you want to apply $f$ twice, you could use function composition `(f . f) x`, or $(f \circ f)\ x$ in math notation.

Comment: Yes I know, I could make a function composition. But the point that I do not understand is, why `f` apply to `f` is infinite? Can I imagine, it is a function recursion? What does so symbols mean? Can you please in a very easy way?

Comment: The application isn't infinite, but the type is. If you don't believe me, here's a challenge: try to think of a type for it. Without higher rank polymorphism, it's not possible.